# Leaflet js - memory leak accessing GeoJSON REST Api

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, leaflet, geojson

With Leaflet, I need to refresh the features displayed after map movements (pan, zoom).

I access a GeoJSON REST Api thus:

```
function getFeatures( map, layer, table, user ) {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var style = layer.module.spatial.style || undefined;

  var params = {
    geojson: true,
    bbox: bounds.toBBoxString(),
    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
    limit: 200 // limit returned features
  }; 

  fetch ('api/organisations/' + user.organisation + '/objects/' + table + '?' 
    + new URLSearchParams (params))
  .then( response => response.json())
  .then( data => {
    layer.addData (data)
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log("Fetch error on table " + table + ': ' + err);
  });
}

export default function(options, map, L, user) {
  var layer = L.geoJson(null, { /*... styling, popup ...*/ });

  map.on('moveend', function(evt) {
    var map = evt.target;
    getFeatures(map, layer, options._id, user );
  });
}

/*
 * ... in calling script:
 */
map.addLayer(layer);
```

All works fine, but memory usage (measured in Chrome devtools) rockets steadily upwards, and performance becomes poor.

I imagine that I need to be freeing something, presumably in my "moveend" handler, but have been unable to locate any examples suggesting what I should do.

I've tried `map.removeLayer(layer)` and `map.addLayer(layer)` either side of `layer.addData (data)`, this made no difference.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspecting leaflet.js doc, layer seems to have a [`remove` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-remove). But in order to invoke it, you will likely need to get a reference to the geojson layer object. So perhaps something like the following?

```js
function getFeatures( map, layer, table, user ) {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var style = layer.module.spatial.style || undefined;

  var params = {
    geojson: true,
    bbox: bounds.toBBoxString(),
    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
    limit: 200 // limit returned features
  }; 

  fetch ('api/organisations/' + user.organisation + '/objects/' + table + '?' 
    + new URLSearchParams (params))
  .then( response => response.json())
  .then( data => {
    layer.addData (data)
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.log("Fetch error on table " + table + ': ' + err);
  });
}

let layer // not a huge fan of using var, but I believe you can use var here if you insist

export default function(options, map, L, user) {
  if (!!layer) {
    layer.remove()
  }
  layer = L.geoJson(null, { /*... styling, popup ...*/ });

  map.on('moveend', function(evt) {
    var map = evt.target;
    getFeatures(map, layer, options._id, user );
  });
}

/*
 * ... in calling script:
 */
map.addLayer(layer);
```

You may need to do some debouncing, since `getFeatures` etc is an async call, and you could have some race condition shenanigans.

Comment: Yes, this has resolved the "leaking" issue (although has exposed many others ...). I'll post the version of the code I ended up with, but I'm coming from OpenLayers where I create my layer once (& add it to e.g. a list of layers in a layer selector), then add and remove features as the user navigates. This technique of destroying and recreating the layer on each map zoom or pan seems overkill ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how my code ended up, thanks to @pandamakes answer:

```
let layer;

function getFeatures( map, L, options, user ) { // Called on every map pan/zoom
  var table = options._id;
  if (!! layer) {
    layer.remove();
  }

  if(options.spatial.geometry == 'polygon') {
    layer = L.geoJson(null, {
      style: function (feature) {
        return feature.style || undefined;
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.plats_namn); 
      }
    });
  } else {
    layer = L.geoJson(null, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, feature.style || undefined);
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.art);
      }
    });
  }

  /* 
   * Set the module on the source for filtering 
   */
  layer.module = options;
  layer.name = name;

    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var style = layer.module.spatial.style || undefined;

    var params = {
      geojson: true,
      bbox: bounds.toBBoxString(),
      srs: 'EPSG:4326'
      style: style,
      limit: 200
    }; 

    fetch ('api/organisations/' + user.organisation + '/objects/' + table + '?' 
      + new URLSearchParams (params))
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => {
      layer.addData (data)
      map.addLayer(layer)
    })
    .catch( err => {
console.log("Fetch error on table " + table + ': ' + err);
    });
}

export default function(options, map, L, user) {
  map.on('moveend', function(evt) {
    var map = evt.target;
    getFeatures(map, L, options, user );
  });
}
```

Unsatisfactory, but memory leak gone ...

It would be preferable to simply remove the existing features on the layer on every pan/zoom; I shall look into the possibilities of doing this.